# STRTOTIME in php returning blank value

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

The dataset value is returning blank, no error on logfile.

```
$edate = trim($_POST['txtedate']); //user inputs date 12-01-2021
$int_effective_date = new DateTime(strtotime($edate));
echo "edate:- ".$edate."<br />";        
echo "strtotime_edate:- ".strtotime($edate)."<br />";
echo "dateset:- ".strtotime($int_effective_date->format('Y/m/d'));
```

Result:

> edate:- 2021-01-12
>
> strtotime_edate:- 1610389800
>
> dateset:-

Comment: You're trying to convert from a user input to a timestamp to a DateTime object to a string to a timestamp - why? Specifically, the problem is that you can't pass a unix timestamp to the DateTime constructor, but all of this would be a lot clearer if you cut out a lot of the intermediate steps.

Comment: [Unable to reproduce](https://3v4l.org/AKWnK).

Comment: @El_Vanja yes,why dateset's date is Thu, 03 Feb 6000 23:00:00 GMT? instead of 12/01/21

Comment: That's a question that's already been answered by @iainn in his comment - `DateTime` doesn't handle timestamps as constructor arguments.

Comment: @iainn that isn't strictly true: you can prepend a Unix timestamp with "@" and `DateTime` accepts it

Comment: @El_Vanja this is reproducible if you remember the _2038 Epochalypse_

Comment: @Steven I was referring to the exact code in the question. It simply does not match what was presented as the result.

Comment: @El_Vanja sorry, I didn't explain that very well... It does match the result. Just not with modern(or 64 bit) PHP versions; you can even test this by activating `End of Life` versions on your linked example.

Comment: @Steven Hm, yeah, I completely forgot to test the `eol` versions. I keep forgetting that ancient PHP is still used nowadays. Seems like 5.2.0 - 5.2.5 reproduce this.

Answer (score 1):

To paraphrase @iainn: I'm not 100% sure why you're changing back and forth between `DateTime` objects and function calls to `strtotime`?

However, I can explain the most likely issue with your code...

**strtotime**

Firstly, let's clarify that `12-01-2021` is in the format (`d-m-Y`)? Hopefully it is, in which case PHPs `strtotime` function understands it correctly and produces a Unix timestamp (i.e. seconds passed since start of 1970)...

```
strtotime("12-01-2021");

// Output: 1610409600

// Notes:
//     - Possible slight variations based on locale etc.
//     - Lookup: date_default_timezone_set
//     - This is with "UTC"
```

**DateTime**

You then pass that timestamp to `DateTime` but neglect to inform `DateTime` what kind of timestamp it is...

```
$int_effective_date = new DateTime(strtotime($edate));

// Is the same as...

$int_effective_date = new DateTime(1610409600);
```

However, `DateTime` doesn't see your timestamp as `incorrect` and tries to process it anyway...

1. In the format: `HisYmd`
2. But your input is too short for that so it only matches `HisY`

   ```
   Time => 16:10
   Year => 9600
   ```
3. Given the lack of data `DateTime` then fills in the blanks with `today` (example: 2021-02-05)

   ```
   Day   => 05
   Month => 02
   ```
4. Which give you a complete timestamp of: `9600-02-05 16:10:40`

**strtotime *from* DateTime**

Your next line of code then passes that timestamp back into a `strtotime` call...

```
echo "dateset:- ".strtotime($int_effective_date->format('Y/m/d'));

// Is the same as...

echo "dateset:- ".strtotime("9600/02/05");
```

Now, `strtotime` will always return *something*. Which means the first problem is that you're using `echo` which doesn't output `(bool) false`.

Try:

```
var_dump(strtotime("9600/02/05"));
```

You might ask, why doesn't that happen in the linked code example from @El_Vanja?

**Answer**

The answer to that, I believe, is that your PHP version is not up to date and anything over the `32 bit` date range is going to return `(bool) false` from `strtotime`.

To fix this specific problem I suggest you update your PHP version (and OS if you haven't moved to 64 bit!)

However, further to that, I strongly suggest you stick to the `DateTime` object/class. It saves you from all of these annoying bugs if nothing else...

For reference:

```
echo strtotime( (new DateTime("@1610409600"))->format("Y-m-d") ); // Output: 1610409600
echo strtotime( (new DateTime("2021-01-12"))->format("Y-m-d") );  // Output: 1610409600
```